# wayland-ivi-extension build error on ubuntu16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, wayland

I followed the steps of GENIVI guide.

Building wayland-ivi-extension:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/GENIVI/wayland-ivi-extension.git

$ mkdir build-wayland-ivi-extension

$ cd build-wayland-ivi-extension

$ cmake ./ -DBUILD_ILM_API_TESTS=1 ../wayland-ivi-extension

$ make

$ make install
```

I got the error when I executed:

```
cmake ./ -DBUILD_ILM_API_TESTS=1 ../wayland-ivi-extension
```

Error log：

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting C compile features

-- Detecting C compile features - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting CXX compile features

-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 

-- Checking for module 'wayland-client>=1.13.0'


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:532 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  protocol/CMakeLists.txt:25 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nlin/Wayland/build-wayland-ivi-extension/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Question might be asked to ubuntu stackexchange site

Answer (score 0):

some installed packages are required to compile `Wayland-ivi-extension`
Pre-requisite: 
- Weston
- CMake required (version 2.6 or higher)
- Open GLES and EGL for example applications
- Gtest for the test suite

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config 
sudo apt-get install libwayland-dev
```

and then try to run `cmake` command. If there is any error feel free to contact.